# How does git --no-merged option work

Tags: git

How does the `git branch -r --no-merged` work?

Does it check to see if all commits in one branch already exist in the original parent branch?

And what about cherry picks? Is it smart enough to say that a commit from 1 branch has already been cherry picked back into the original parent branch?

And if a branch has already been merged and new commits have been added will it pick that branch up as not being merged?

Comment: Have you read the man page? it says "Only list branches whose tips are not reachable from the specified commit"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, that comments from @Hasturkun says it all to be honest, but you have 3 questions:

**1. Does it check to see if all commits in one branch already exist in the original parent branch?**

Not trying to be repetitive @Hasturkun quote says: *"Only list branches whose tips are not reachable from the specified commit".*

In this specific case think of the git tree of commits as a tube/underground map. You can only travel backwards from one node/station to the other.

```
master    : - - - -0 
                    \   
branchA   :          E - - - - F - - - - G
```

If on `master` you run `git branch --no-merge` and taking the manual page definition? Can you  reach G (the tip of of `branchA`) from `master`'s HEAD, commit 0? No you can't, so `branchA` will be listed as a non-merged branch.

How about if you run `git branch --no-merge` from the HEAD of `branchA`(commit G)? Will `master` be a non-merged branch? No, it is considered a merged branch, trivial to understand why given the example before.

How about this example?

```
master    : - - - -0
                    \   
branchA   :          E - - - - F - - - - G - - - Z
                               \                /
branchB   :                     Y - - - W - - -
```

Output of running git branch --no-merged in all 3 branches:

```
master
  branchA
  branchB
branchA (nothing)
branchB (nothing)
```

**2. And what about cherry picks? Is it smart enough to say that a commit from 1 branch has already been cherry picked back into the original parent branch?**

Cherry-picks create a completely different commitId, so I only use them when I really have to. Since it creates a completely different commit, the trees will differ:

Look at this experiment I just did, consider master and branchA the same:

Experience 1) Using merge

```
(master)$ touch empty && git add . && git commit -am "File Added"
(master)$ checkout branchA
(branchA)$ git branch --no-merged
  master
(branchA)$ git merge master
(branchA)$ git branch --no-merged
  // outputs nothing
```

Experience 2) Using cherry-pick

```
(master)$ touch empty && git add . && git commit -am "File Added"
(master)$ checkout branchA
(branchA)$ git branch --no-merged
  master
(branchA)$ git cheery-pick <commitID from above>
(branchA)$ git branch --no-merged
  master
```

**3. And if a branch has already been merged and new commits have been added will it pick that branch up as not being merged?**

Yes, because of all stated above.